# Using variable to loop through rows in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Total noob, having trouble using a variable to loop through row. 
I'd like to print the contents of the column `header_en`. So I:

Set `$lang` to `en`, connect to db and SELECT *

Then:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo "<h3>Headline is: $row['header_$lang]</h3>";
    echo "<p>Author: $row[author]</p>";
}
```

I've been searching for hours, tried concatenating around the `$lang` variable, all sorts of stuff... no luck. My syntax-fu isn't all that strong yet.

Any pointers?

Comment: i believe answers below have solved your problem , if yes than mark one of them as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
echo "<h3>Headline is: " . $row['header_'.$lang] . "</h3>";
```

or even

```
$headerLanguage = 'header_'.$lang;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) { 
    echo "<h3>Headline is: " . $row[$headerLanguage] . "</h3>"; 
    echo "<p>Author: $row[author]</p>"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Ed's solution below works too, but Mark was faster on the draw.

For anybody struggling: my error was missing the final .

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need

```
echo "<h3>Headline is: ".$row['header_'.$lang]."</h3>"; 
echo "<p>Author: ".$row['author']."</p>";
```

Comment: Fix your first variable name ;) You missed a "_" sign.

Answer (score 0):

If you use quotes in php you need to know this:

```
echo 'single quotes are faster, but dont see variables ' . $variable;
echo "double quotes can see them like so: $variable";
echo "to show array in doble quotes use brackets {$array['key']}";
```